# Unity 3D rolling animation stops mid way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im new to unity started few days ago, and new to c#
I have a problem where the animation is not played to the end its just cut in the midle here is youtube link so you can check it out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz5TWh7dTqY

This is the code I made myself for animations

```
public class PlayerControllerAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
public Animator anim;

void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{

    //if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0) 
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") !=0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    }else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        anim.SetBool("isSprinting", true);
    }else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isSprinting", false);
    }
     //if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V))
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Roll"))
    {
        
        anim.SetBool("isRolling", true);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRolling", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Roll") && anim)
    {
        anim.StopPlayback();
        //Stop(GetComponent<Animator>());
    }
 }
}
```

and this code I just copy paste from internet

```
private Health Hp;
private Rigidbody Rb;

private Animator Anim;

public float DelayBeforeInvisible = 0.2f;
public float InvisibleDuration = 0.5f;

public float DodgeCoolDown = 1;
private float ActCooldown;

public float PushAmt = 3;

void Start()
{
    Hp = GetComponent<Health>();
    Rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
}
void Update()
{
    bool Roll = Input.GetButtonDown("Roll");
    if (ActCooldown <= 0)
    {
        Anim.ResetTrigger("Roll");
        if (Roll)
        {
            Dodge();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ActCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    void Dodge()
    {
        ActCooldown = DodgeCoolDown;
        Hp.Invisible(DelayBeforeInvisible, InvisibleDuration);

        Rb.AddForce(transform.forward * PushAmt, ForceMode.Force);

        Anim.SetTrigger("Roll");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is probably a problem in your Unity Animation Tree, please check that the transitions work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because your roll animations exit state is set to `isRolling = false` In your code it says `if (Input.GetButtonDown("Roll"))` `else` which means the moment you let go of the key, `isRolling = false`. If this is the issue you can solve it by either ticking the "Has exit time" box in your animations transition. Or you can create a timer float to revert isRolling to false in a specific time.